# Code Your C#/ASP.NET App to Provide SSO via OneLogin - getting errors

Tags: .net, authentication

Getting error such as

> Type '_Default' already defines a member called 'Page_Load' with the same parameter types.

I had tried to create same project in .NET web app as well as in MVC but getting same error.

Code referred from: https://github.com/onelogin/dotnet-saml

Answer (score 0):

1. That error has nothing to do with the dotnet-saml library.
2. Don't use the Onelogin toolkit. As it says in the readme on the library, it lacks important security checks.

Comment: then how to implement simple POC for ADFS authentication using SAML in .net application

Comment: You can use my library, Sustainsys.Saml2. There are several example applications in the repo. Or any of the other commercial or OSS libraries available.

Comment: @AndersAbel Can Sustainsys  be used to create both IdP and SP? Also can it work in "IdP initiated SSO" scenario?

Comment: @LCJ It is a complete SP implementation. It contains a rough Idp implementation (see https://stubidp.sustainsys.com). It works with Idp initiated SSO, just be aware of the session pinning risk.